# Delete a Row using Fetch API Use Effect - ReactJS

Tags: mysql, reactjs, use-effect

am trying to delete a row based on product code entered, i have 2 functions, one is for search and another is for delete..

Search Function

```
const handleName = e => {
    const idAddProducts = e.target.value;
    e.preventDefault();
    pnName({ ...poName, idaddproducts: idAddProducts });
    handleTable(idAddProducts);
    // handleSubmit(idAddProducts);
    console.log(poName);
  };

 async function handleTable(idAddProducts) {
    const id = poName.idaddproducts;
    const res = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:4000/productslist/" + idAddProducts
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    pnName(data.data);
    console.log(data.data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleTable();
  }, []);
```

Another one is Delete Function

```
  const handleN = e => {
    const idAddProducts = e.target.value;
    e.preventDefault();
    pnName({ ...poName, idaddproducts: idAddProducts });
    handleSubmit(idAddProducts);
    console.log(poName);
  };
async function handleSubmit(idAddProducts) {
    const res = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:4000/productslist/delete/" + idAddProducts
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    pnName(data.data);
    console.log(data.data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleSubmit();
  }, []);
```

Here is the Rendering Part where i map the searched result

```
<TableBody>
    {poName && poName.length ? (
    poName.map(row => (
    <TableRow key={row.idaddproducts}>
    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
    {row.idaddproducts}
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
    {row.productName}
    </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.productId}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.productBrand}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.productQuantity}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.productPrice}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.productType}</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
    ))
    ) : (
    <span>Not Found</span>
    )}
</TableBody>
</Table>
</TableContainer>
<div style={{ paddingBlockEnd: "0px" }}>
<Fab color="secondary" aria-label="edit" onClick={handleN}>
<EditIcon />
</Fab>
</div>
```

So when i add the handleSubmit function directly in to handleName, its getting deleted as i type, so i had to create seperate function as HandleN and call handle submit so that when i click button it should execute,

instead sql throws as Error:

> ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:
>   'undefined'

or

> Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:
>   '[object]%20[object]'

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function DeleteProductsForm() {
  const initialState = {
    idaddproducts: "",
    productName: "",
    productId: "",
    productBrand: "",
    productQuantity: "",
    productPrice: "",
    productType: ""
  };
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState(initialState);

  const handleName = e => {
    const idAddProducts = e.target.value;
    console.log(idAddProducts);
    e.preventDefault();
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: idAddProducts });
    handleList1(idAddProducts);
    console.log(values);
  };

  const handleN = e => {
    const idAddProducts = values.idaddproducts;
    console.log(idAddProducts);
    e.preventDefault();
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: idAddProducts });
    handleList(idAddProducts);
    console.log(values);
  };

  async function handleList1(idAddProducts) {
    const res = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:4000/productslist/" + idAddProducts
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    setValues(data.data);
    console.log(data.data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleList1();
  }, []);

  async function handleList(idAddProducts) {
    const res = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:4000/productslist/delete/" + idAddProducts
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    setValues(data.data);
    console.log(data.data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleList();
  }, []);

  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off" align="center">
      <div className={classes.formGroup}>
        <FormControl>
          <Input
            type="search"
            label="Product ID"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            placeholder="Enter Product Code"
            value={values.idaddproducts}
            name="idaddproducts"
            onChange={e => handleName(e)}
          />
        </FormControl>

        <Button onClick={e => handleN(e)}>Click</Button>
        {values && values.length ? (
          values.map(row => <h5 key={row.idaddproducts}>{row.productName}</h5>)
        ) : (
          <h5>Not Found</h5>
        )}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

if i delete handleList1 function it works fine.. but it wont display data